# Linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $T$ has zero as eigenvalue, then, is $T$ $(a)$ diagonalizable  $(b)$ nilpotent $(c)$ multiplicity of each eigenvalue of $T$ is $1$?
Could you please you give me some hints?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050633/what-do-zero-eigenvalues-mean) should give you some insight into what it means to have   eigenvalues of zero.